# Simple completion for "template" on vim a la sublime ( potentially using YouCompleteMe )?

Tags: vim, sublimetext, youcompleteme

I didn't understand how to use YouCompleteMe to create nice templates like stuff I used to have on sublime.

Two basic examples I would like to achieve:

typing "log" being completed to

```
console.log "\$1"
```

typing "fori" being completed to

```
for \$1 in \$2
  \$3
```

So basically expanding the template then allowing me to quickly filled the spaces and end up on the last "cue".

From what I understood YouCompleteMe does anything you need including *mocha late* and *milkshakes*, but I still have no clue how to do this simple thing.

Answer (score 1):

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.